# How to solve the maven issue getting as could not transfer artifact?

Tags: maven, build

I having a pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.super-poms.jboss6</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>company-app.dbr</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbr</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>MyApp Application</name>
    <description>Multi Deliverables/Modules builder</description>

    <!-- Here you put the properties you need in all your components (Config files, Resource files,... -->
    <properties>
    <sia>dbr</sia>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- override super-poms versions for maven-compiler-plugin since IODA does not have 1.8 yet -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <!-- Here you declare the deliverables of the Application as modules -->

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- This project makes use of Hibernate which is included into JBoss EAP 6+ -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom.eap</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom.eap}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss EAP 6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>  
            <version>2.0.0-beta-2</version>  
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- The JBoss AS plugin deploys your ear to a local JBoss AS container -->
                <!-- Due to Maven's lack of intelligence with EARs we need 
                    to configure the jboss-as maven plugin to skip deployment for all modules. 
                    We then enable it specifically in the ear module. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Use this profile for local Workstation deployment -->
            <id>Eclipse</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>target</name>
                    <value>LOCAL</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <mysql-driver>custom.mysql.default</mysql-driver>
                <databaseUrl>mysql:${sia}devy01.mc2.company.fr:3306/${sia}_db_01</databaseUrl>
                <associatedUser>${sia}_adm</associatedUser>
                <associatedPassWord>${sia}_adm_pwd</associatedPassWord>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!-- Use this profile for DEV server deployment -->
            <id>DEV</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>target</name>
                    <value>DEV</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <mysql-driver>custom.oracle.default</mysql-driver>
                <!-- Uncomment and fill below lines only when building without IODA -->
                <!--
                <databaseUrl>jdbc:oracle:thin:@${sia}devo01.mc2.company.fr:1684/${sia}devo01
                <associatedUser>${sia}_adm</associatedUser>
                <associatedPassWord>${sia}_adm_pwd</associatedPassWord>
                -->
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>RE7</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>target</name>
                    <value>RE7</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <mysql-driver>custom.oracle.default</mysql-driver>
                <!-- Uncomment and fill below lines only when building without IODA -->
                <!--
                <databaseUrl>jdbc:oracle:thin:@${sia}re7o01.mc2.company.fr:1684/${sia}re7o01
                <associatedUser>${sia}_adm</associatedUser>
                <associatedPassWord>${sia}_adm_pwd</associatedPassWord>
                -->
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>OPE</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>target</name>
                    <value>OPE</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <mysql-driver>custom.oracle.default</mysql-driver>
                <!-- Uncomment and fill below lines only when building without IODA -->
                <!--
                <databaseUrl>jdbc:oracle:thin:@${sia}opeo01.mc2.company.fr:1684/${sia}opeo01
                <associatedUser>${sia}_adm</associatedUser>
                <associatedPassWord>${sia}_adm_pwd</associatedPassWord>
                -->
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
  <modules>
    <module>dbr-cnf</module>
    <module>dbr-res</module>
    <module>dbr-app</module>
    <module>dbr-statics</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

When i run `mvn clean install` in cmd prompt i am getting this error

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/company/super-poms/jboss6/
super-pom/1.4/super-pom-1.4.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for company-app.dbr:dbr:1.0: Could not transfe
r artifact com.company.super-poms.jboss6:super-pom:pom:1.4 from/to central (http
s://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePat
h' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountere
d while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for company-app.dbr:dbr:1.0: Could not transfe
r artifact com.company.super-poms.jboss6:super-pom:pom:1.4 from/to central (http
s://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePat
h' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBu
ilder.java:422)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGra
phBuilder.java:419)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor
(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.
java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project company-app.dbr:dbr:1.0 (D:\Public\maven_projects\dbr\dbr\
pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for company-app.dbr:dbr:1.0: Could not tra
nsfer artifact com.company.super-poms.jboss6:super-pom:pom:1.4 from/to central (
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativ
ePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10: Unknown host repo.maven.ap
ache.org -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer
 artifact com.company.super-poms.jboss6:super-pom:pom:1.4 from/to central (https
://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectMod
elResolver.java:197)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectMod
elResolver.java:246)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExterna
lly(DefaultModelBuilder.java:978)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(Defaul
tModelBuilder.java:796)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultMode
lBuilder.java:325)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBu
ilder.java:469)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBu
ilder.java:438)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBu
ilder.java:401)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGra
phBuilder.java:419)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor
(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.
java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
transfer artifact com.company.super-poms.jboss6:super-pom:pom:1.4 from/to centra
l (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Defa
ultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtif
acts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtif
act(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtif
act(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectMod
elResolver.java:193)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not tran
sfer artifact com.company.super-poms.jboss6:super-pom:pom:1.4 from/to central (h
ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transfer
Failed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunne
r.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(Runn
ableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExe
cutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(Basic
RepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownl
oads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Defa
ultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: repo.maven.apache.org

        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInp
utData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1066)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInp
utData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:11
6)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run
(WagonTransporter.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTran
sporter.java:427)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTranspor
ter.java:404)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRu
nner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunne
r.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:130
2)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1171)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1105)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.SystemDefa
ultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:44)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClient
ConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHtt
pClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainC
lientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainC
lientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.Proto
colExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.Retry
Exec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.Redir
ectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.Internal
HttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.Closeabl
eHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute
(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:832)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInp
utData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:983)
        ... 43 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableMo
delException
```

[My folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yeC0.jpg)

[Application files with pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWDyf.jpg)

These are the informations i have in the project with created code, can anyone help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Install this parent before use it :

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.super-poms.jboss6</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
  </parent>
```

or use `version-SNAPSHOT` version with modules.

---

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company.super-poms.jboss6</groupId>
    <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>company-app.dbr</groupId>
<artifactId>dbr</artifactId>
<version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

**and all others modules use version 1.4-SNAPSHOT**

```
<parent> 
<groupId>company-app.dbr</groupId>
<artifactId>dbr</artifactId>
<version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

    <artifactId>dbr-cnf</artifactId>
    <name>dbr-cnf</name>
    <description>dbr-cnf</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Comment: im just new to maven can u tell me how to use version-SNAPSHOT